# is it possible to download images from cache memory in picasso?

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader, picasso

I was using `UniversalImageDownloader` for my app.in UIL we can save images from cache memory.

```
 File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(imageUrl);
            if (cachedImage.exists())
            {// code for save 2 sd
                           }
```

Is it possible in picasso?

Comment: you really should stop duplicating your questions !!

Comment: @AndroSelva what can i do .this question is not clear.thats only i gave the exact details in another question.

Comment: I completely understand that. But you are still missing a point. You don't say why you exactly need to get the image from cache!! why?

Comment: @AndroSelva I answered there

Comment: I get your question.. But there are lot many ways to do it. and unfortunately the solution is a little lengthy and I am afraid your question will receive much attention since it will need someone who can work on your problem..

Comment: @AndroSelva i will try some other stuffs

Comment: Hi, I am having some problem with jar I downloaded for Picasso. If you have your sample can you send it across to my mail? Will that be a problem?

Comment: @AndroSelva [Try this](https://twitter.com/dnkoutso/status/369987447834173440)

Comment: I'm doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808114/picasso-loading-of-image-spawned-inside-asynctask

Comment: You should really be careful when doing this, if you hold a reference to images in the cache you prevent those images from being garbage collected once they are evicted from the cache. This can cause `OutOfMemoryExceptions` and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a private Method in Picasso -

```
Bitmap quickMemoryCacheCheck(String key) {
    Bitmap cached = cache.get(key);
    if (cached != null) {
      stats.dispatchCacheHit();
    } else {
      stats.dispatchCacheMiss();
    }
    return cached;
  }
```

Modify the source according to your need.

Comment: Cache cache ; StatsSnapshot stats; i declared  this variable in my activity is that ok?

Comment: `quickMemoryCacheCheck` is a private Method of `Picasso.class`. You have to pull the source from `GIT` and modify the source code.

Comment: Ok but how to get the key value?

Comment: @yea in picasso class i have seen stats and cache class to pull.but how to get the key value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this , Use OkHttp & Picasso:

```
public class APP extends Application{
  public static OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Picasso.Builder b = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(this);
    b.downloader(okHttpDownloader);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(b.build());
 }
}
```

Then get the File from OkHttp local cache:

```
Downloader.Response res = APP.okHttpDownloader.load(Uri.parse(your image Url),0);
Log.i(TAG,"Get From DISK: " + res.isCached() );
storeImageFile(res.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Why does it have to extend application and can you expand on the method storeImageFile, include the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get bitmap from ImangeView onSuccess() callback

```
Picasso.with(context).load(path).into(imageView, new Callback(){
    public void onSuccess() {
      Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
      //save bitmap to sdcard
   } 
   public void onError() {}
}
```

WARNING: Saved bitmap may be different to original bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will first make Picasso load image from cache, if failed then download and display image in imageView

You can debug memory performance with

> Picasso.with(appContext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

- green (memory, best performance)
- blue (disk, good performance)
- red (network, worst performance).

  ```
       //Debugging memory performance https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-cache-indicators-logging-stats
      //TODO remove on deployment
      Picasso.with(appContext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

      //Try to load image from cache
      Picasso.with(appContext)
              .load(imageUrl)
              .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .resize(100, 100)
              .error(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
              .into(markerImageView, new Callback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess() {

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError() {

                      // Try online if cache failed
                      Picasso.with(appContext)
                              .load(imageUrl)
                              .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                              .resize(100, 100)
                              .error(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
                              .into(markerImageView);
                  }
              });
  ```